# How to print @ symbol in Ocaml

Tags: string, ocaml

I would like to print the symbol @ in Ocaml but it is always omitted from the content.
Can some body guide me the solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Although Chuck was able to guess what your question was, you should include a minimum program exhibiting the behavior you allude to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using `printf` or similar. The "@" character has special meaning in format strings. To get a literal "@" in the string, use `%@`.

Comment: Thanks @chuck I used `Pretty_utils.sfprintf`. It seems that `%@` does not work for `Pretty_utils.sfprintf`. Do you have another solution?

Comment: `@@` was deprecated in 3.12.1, if you're using an earlier release of OCaml you can try that.

Comment: I can confirm that `Pretty_utils.sfprintf` (which is a Frama-C-specific function) correctly handles `%a`. What is your exact code?